# HTML5 semantics article tag for main content

Tags: html, semantics, article

**Semantics: You want to get them right but sometimes they're just confusing.**

Website document structure:

```
<body>
    <header>
    <div id="main">
        <header> (not on every page)
        <div id="content">
        <footer> (not on every page)
    <aside>
    <footer>
```

Is it semantically correct to replace **div#main** with an **article** tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/ that is a valid semantic way of coding. It is referred to as "A weblog-style `<article>`".

Depending on your structure you might be able to replace `#content` with an article as well.

Do not forget to include http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ and while you're at it if you serve your site over **https** also look into Protocol Relative Url (Google for it), so you don't have to detect the switch between http and https.

Comment: Thanks! HTML5 Shiv is already included. To be clear, the usage of an article element is semantically correct when the content of it makes sense on it's own?

Comment: As per HTML5doctor: "The <article> element is a specialised kind of <section>; it has a more specific semantic meaning than <section> in that it is an independent, self-contained block of related content. We could use <section>, but using <article> gives more semantic meaning to the content." - so I'd say yes! :)

Answer (score 9):

To raise the dead on this question, the currently accepted answer will soon be incorrect. There has been an extension draft for a `<main>` element targeted for exactly what you need. Furthermore it automates the ARIA `role="main"` in the browser for better accessibility. Please see this link for more info: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-extensions/raw-file/tip/maincontent/index.html

> This specification is an extension to the HTML5 specification [HTML5]. It defines an element to be used for the identification of
>   the main content area of a document. All normative content in the
>   HTML5 specification, unless specifically overridden by this
>   specification, is intended to be the basis for this specification.
>
> The main element formalises the common practice of identification of
>   the main content section of a document using the id values such as
>   'content' and 'main'. It also defines an HTML element that embodies
>   the semantics and function of the WAI-ARIA [ARIA] landmark role=main.

```
<main>

  <h1>Apples</h1>
 <p>The apple is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree.</p>

 <article>
 <h2>Red Delicious</h2>
  <p>These bright red apples are the most common found in many
  supermarkets.</p>
  <p>... </p>
  <p>... </p>
  </article>

  <article>
  <h2>Granny Smith</h2>
  <p>These juicy, green apples make a great filling for
  apple pies.</p>
  <p>... </p>
  <p>... </p>
  </article>

</main>
```

Comment: There's a note in the article saying that `main` tag goes to HTML5.1 spec. Looking forward for wider support

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more appropriate to replace it with a `<section>` tag. The `<article>` tag is meant for stuff like blog posts, forum posts, or newspaper articles (hence the name of the tag).

In contrast, the `<section>` tag is meant for more generic parts of content in your document and thus is better suited in this case.

This is all [much better explained by Mark Pilgrim](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/semantics.html#new-elements) at [DiveIntoHTML5.ep.io](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io)

Comment: The article element can easily stand on it's own but isn't the section element best accompanied by other section elements?

Comment: Maybe, but as far as I understand your structure you've got another `div` with id content so I guess that's where the `<article>` tag is more suitable and for the encompassing element a `<section>` is more appropriate.

Comment: a `article` in a `section` is probably not what you want here, it would create a wrong outline. using `article` only would be fine here. it is not restricted to be used in content that could be described with the term "article". the element name must not be read/understood that way.

Comment: The `<article>` element defines an area which can be stand alone, the `<section>` element defines a thematic break.